# USB File Explorer stops recognizing discs in external Blu-Ray drive after hibernation

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, usb-3, optical-drive, external-drive

This is my first question on this website. I hope it's the right place to ask this type of question here.

I have a problem with an external USB 3.0 Blu-Ray drive ([ASUS BW-16D1H-U PRO](https://www.asus.com/Commercial-Data-Storage/BW16D1HU_PRO)). If I hibernate my PC with the drive still plugged in, then, after the PC has booted up again, Windows File Explorer fails to recognize any disc I insert into the drive afterwards. The drive doesn't seem to spin up at all, and after a short while, Windows ejects its tray and presents a "Please insert a disk into drive" dialog.

The strangest thing is that the disc *does* get recognized in other places: Disk Management correctly displays the total size of its contents, and programs like [ImgBurn](https://www.imgburn.com/) can also see that a disc is inserted, and it is even possible to make the drive read and verify the disc with such a program (however, this process does not make it appear in File Explorer).

This glitch happens regardless of the type of the disc (CD, DVD, Blu-Ray). However, it seems that the problem occurs *only* if the drive is empty by the time the PC has resumed from hibernation. If any disc is already present inside the drive before the PC boots up again, then it gets recognized immediately, and everything works normally from that point.

The device manager always shows that the drive is working properly, and the event log does not have any events that may be related to this problem. The only solution short of rebooting the PC is to either power-cycle the drive (it has an external power supply and an on/off switch), or unplug it from the USB port and then plug it back in.

Has anyone else ever experienced anything similar to what I've described? Any tips on how this may be solved will be greatly appreciated. My OS is Windows 10 1903 (64-bit). According to the official update utility downloaded from the Asus website, the drive has the latest firmware.

Comment: When this happens, does disconnecting and reconnecting the drive, solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it does. I mentioned it in my question: "The only solution short of rebooting the PC is to either power-cycle the drive, or unplug it and then plug it back in". By unplugging, I meant unplugging from the USB port, not the power outlet. I'll edit the question to clarify.